# Iterate over json in shell

Tags: json, bash

I have a JSON that starts like this (I have edited the end of the file to close the opening bracket to make it a valid file):

```
{
"YRPLBn9VEgpB4pc": {
    "name": "Bright",
    "lights": [
        "8"
    ],
    "owner": "VHB3Xij-S9AfghoMDL6ccgCEOOE00Fs43nzBbNgR",
    "recycle": false,
    "locked": false,
    "appdata": {
        "version": 1,
        "data": "7prbY_r03_d05"
    },
    "picture": "",
    "lastupdated": "2018-07-24T12:51:03",
    "version": 2
},
"oRvYDYW6dMmGoUw": {
    "name": "Dimmed",
    "lights": [
        "8"
    ],
    "owner": "VHB3Xij-S9AfghoMDL6ccgCEOOE00Fs43nzBbNgR",
    "recycle": false,
    "locked": false,
    "appdata": {
        "version": 1,
        "data": "jBjTp_r03_d06"
    },
    "picture": "",
    "lastupdated": "2018-07-24T12:51:03",
    "version": 2
}
}
```

It is returned by the Philips Hue Clip api in response to a query asking for all scenes saved on the bridge.

I want to iterate over this (ideally in bash, but I am open to suggestions) so that I can get the items "YRPLBn9VEgpB4pc", "oRvYDYW6dMmGoUw" etc. I know how I would get the values from key pairs*, but I don't really understand what these items are - object ids, perhaps?

*get value from "name" using jq:

```
for row in $(echo "${sample}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
    _jq() {
    echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1};
    };
    echo $(_jq '.name');
done
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `keys[]`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually keys_unsorted[] from the duplicate was what I needed.